# Match many regexes on the same string at once

Tags: c#, regex

I have a number of regular expressions that attempt to find items in a very long (~100 pages of text) string, with each looking for a particular thing (i.e. one looks for one type of information, another looks for a different type, etc).

Each regex group will have ~50 matches or so in the text, but it takes a while to run them all in sequence.

Is there a way that I can run all the of regular expressions on a string at once, or otherwise create a regular expression where the capture groups can occur in any order (any number of times)?

Comment: Wasn't `Parallel.ForEach` enough?

Comment: @L.B it still means that the string is being iterated over many times. Is there a way to make that once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the single regexes into a large regex using groups and alternation:

```
bigregex = "(?:" + regex1 + "|" + regex2 + "|" + regex3 + ")"
```

However, this will only give you the desired result if the matches of each regex can never overlap, and if you're not using numbered capturing groups with backreferences.

Comment: So I am not using numbered capturing groups or backreferences, but at the same time, will this allow the groups to match in any order any number of times (and is there any hoping of adapting the code should I want to use numbered backreferences)

Comment: Also, all of the regexes are capturing. Is that going to be an issue?

Comment: I think it will allow this (referring to your first comment), but I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean. Can you give an example? About adapting the code - if you're planning on doing that, better start using named capturing groups exclusively. Other than that, it won't matter whether a subregex is capturing or not.

Comment: so if the text is `11 22 4` group 1 is `(?<num>\d)` and group 2 is `(?<space>\s)` you are saying to do `(:?(?<num>\d)|(?<space>\s))`? When I do that I get 8 matches (correctly) but three groups per match (not sure why that is, and I don't really want it). Ideas?

Comment: The point of alternation is to match the FIRST regex, and if not, try the one on the right side of the `|`. If they ALL need to match, you cannot do this in a single regex.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis see my comment above?

Comment: If that's the case, you would need to wrap the entire alternation in a single named capture group like............... `(?<everything>\d|\s|\w|\d{6}|\w{7})`

Comment: @soandos: How do you mean "three groups per match"? It would really help if you showed some example text, some example regexes, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not exactly what you need, but may spark an idea.  I use this as a single pass, multi-token, find and replace.

```
public static string MultiReplace(this string target, Dictionary<string, string> replacementDictionary)
    {
                    return Regex.Replace(target, "(" + String.Join("|", replacementDictionary.Keys.ToArray()) + ")", match => replacementDictionary[match.Value]);
    }
```

Comment: The regular expressions are important as capture groups, not as replacements. Ideas on how to adapt this?